# How to get System Model using GoLang Library.Please refer my image

Tags: go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbi3c.png)

The above image details getting from the windows systeminfo command output. I need a system model in the Golang library.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too. Images as code are useless: If the link gets down, the question becomes meaningless (and so do the answers it has gathered). Please use good old copy&paste ;)

Comment: And, BTW, I need a sufficient supply of beer for the rest of my life. I started saving money - what have you tried so far to get your system model?

Comment: I need for system model name using golang library or command

Answer (score -1):

With Windows, you can call `systeminfo` command then filter it with regex.

```golang
func main() {
    c := exec.Command(`systeminfo`)
    output,err:= c.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    s := string(output)
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:System Model: +)(.+)`)
    result:=re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    if len(result)>0{
        println(result[1])
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/1vWjrpuonxW)

Comment: Explanation of downvote: While this technically gives you the data required, one would need to parse the output of `systeminfo` to gain access to the model, which is  specifically what OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks, Markus. But I need a library, because I have to execute the code in the French language machine.

Comment: @Thiru Questions for libraries are off-topic.